# Not ableto get the updated global variable value in confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, confirmation

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var customDiv  ="hello";
   $(function () {
    var $form = $("#authNotificationForm");

    var startItems = $form.serializeArray();     
    startItems = convertSerializedArrayToHash(startItems);

    $("#authNotificationSubmit").click(function (e) {  
        var currentItems = $form.serializeArray();
        currentItems = convertSerializedArrayToHash(currentItems);

        var itemsToSubmit = hashDiff(startItems, currentItems);

        for (var item in itemsToSubmit) {
            customDiv = "test";
        }
    });

  $(".confirm").confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want update the following changes?" + customDiv,
        confirm: function (button) {
            // do something
        },
        cancel: function (button) {
            // do something
        },
        confirmButton: "Yes I am",
        cancelButton: "No",
        post: true
    });
</script>
```

All I am trying to do is on form load get the serializeArray  of the form. Then after changing the fields again on submit click get a new serializedArray  of form compare the 2 and get which fields were changed then on the confirmation box just show the field that were changed by the user. But the confirmation box is displaying hello instead of test.
It is my assumption that the confirmation box text is already loaded on document ready and it is never updated , so it always has the global variable value which is set  on document ready.
(I am getting the updated values correctly so the serialization and the hashDiff functions are fine that not the issue the issue is only getting this values to the confirmation box.)
Thanks for the concern..

Comment: Can you verify that `itemsToSubmit` is indeed not empty?

Comment: yes its not empty I saw it using debugger the code inside the for loop is executing the customDiv value changes in the watch window. But when the confirmation box opens it still has the global variable value which is set on load.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are missing `});` somewhere in your script (probably right after `$("#authNotificationSubmit").click`. You create the `confirm` modal right away, it always uses the initial value of `customDiv`. I'm not sure how `.confirm` works, can you change the text somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `text:` option at load time. Changing `customDiv` later doesn't affect it because the concatenation was done earlier.

Instead of binding the confirmation dialog directly to the button, use `$.confirm` so you can pass arguments at the time of the call:

```
$(".confirm").click(function() {
    $.confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want update the following changes?" + customDiv,
        confirm: function (button) {
            // do something
        },
        cancel: function (button) {
            // do something
        },
        confirmButton: "Yes I am",
        cancelButton: "No",
        post: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your time and effort in helping me out ..Is it possible for you to explain it to me why the direct binding on the button was not working correctly?? I am really confused at this point.

Comment: You call `$("#.confirm").confirm()` at load time, and supply a text option. The concatenation happens at that time, because it's just an object literal -- it's not a function that gets called later when the button is clicked.

Comment: In general, if you want to write something that performs a calculation later, it has to be in a function. If it's just ordinary arguments, it gets executed at that immediate time.

Comment: Ohh ok got it .. such a core concept, I would have never thought of it that way ..thanks again.